# How can I add a corner label to the upper left corner of the entire matrix, like the format in the picture

Tags: equations

[image]

How can I add a corner label to the upper left corner of the entire matrix, like the format in the picture

Comment: It's going to be difficult to suggest modifications to a code we can't see... Please read about [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) and edit your question accordingly. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The command `\prescript` from `mathtools` can be used to write subscripts and superscripts on the left.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
\prescript{A}{}{P} = \prescript{A}{}{\begin{bmatrix} P_x \\ P_y \\ P_z \end{bmatrix}}
\]
\end{document}
```